# Renaming pdf files with a batch file

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I need to either write a batch file or a vbscript that will rename files. I need to keep everything in the file name up to the second "." but delete what comes after the second dot.

This is a sample of what the file names look like:

```
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn.xxxxxxxx.dddddddddd.pdf
```

- `n`= 16 numbers 0-9
- `x`= date in this format ex:02232008
- `d`= 10 numbers 0-9, *this is the part of the file name that I want to delete*.

I need the d's from the sample above to be deleted but keep the rest of the file name the same. I need to be able to run this batch file on a folder that contains about 3,000 pdf files. It can either be put right back into the same folder or outputted into a different folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBScript, you can use something like

```
' the file paths. hardcoded, but you could alternatively collect these via command line parameters
Const IN_PATH = "path\to\directory"
Const OUT_PATH = "path\to\another\directory"

' check that the directories exist. you could create them instead, but here
' it just throws an error as that's easier
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if not fso.FolderExists(IN_PATH) then
    err.raise 1,, "Path '" & IN_PATH & "' not found"
end if
if not fso.FolderExists(OUT_PATH) then
    err.raise 1,, "Path '" & OUT_PATH & "' not found"
end if

dim infolder: set infolder = fso.GetFolder(IN_PATH)
dim file
for each file in infolder.files
    dim name: name = file.name
    dim parts: parts = split(name, ".")
    ' we're expecting a file format of a.b.c.pdf
    ' so we should have 4 elements in the array (zero-indexed, highest bound is 3)
    if UBound(parts) = 3 then
        ' rebuild the name with the 0th, 1st and 3rd elements
        dim newname: newname = parts(0) & "." & parts(1) & "." & parts(3)
        ' use the move() method to effect the rename
        file.move fso.buildpath(OUT_PATH, newname)
    else
        ' log the fact that there's an erroneous file name
        WScript.Echo "Unexpected file format: '" & name & "'"
    end if
next 'file
```

You would run it in a batch file thus, redirecting output to a log file

```
cscript rename-script.vbs > logfile.txt
```

This assumes that you can simply rely on the period to delimit the parts of the file name rather than the specifics of the format of the delimited parts.

---

To rearrange the date, which I think is in the `parts(1)` array element, you can simply extract each bit of the string because it's in a specific format:

```
'date in format mmddyyyy
dim month_, day_, year_, date_
month_ = left(parts(1), 2)
day_ = mid(parts(1), 3, 2)
year_ = right(parts(1), 4)
date_ = year_ & month_ & day_ ' now yyyymmdd
```

so when rebuilding the filename, you can replace `parts(1)` with the new formatted date

```
dim newname: newname = parts(0) & "." & date_ & "." & parts(3)
```

Comment: This script works perfectly! Thanks so much for the help. The only thing I did not use was the logfile. This final piece should complete my automation. Thanks again.

Comment: May I throw one more variation of the script your way? I need to be able to sort these renamed files base on date. The only problem with doing this is that the date part of the file extension is in this format:  nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn.dddddddd.pdf where dddddddd is like this 01232009 (January 23, 2009). If there is a January 23, 2008 then this would not be sorted in order based on date. In order to sort these I need to be able to move the 2009 or last four of the d's in front of the first 4 d's. do you see there being anyway of doing this? Maybe through another script with a different delimiter?

Comment: Wow!!! Unbelievable. Flawless. This script is going to save soooo much time. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ delims=. tokens=1-4" %%F IN (`DIR /B /A-D "C:\Path\To\PDFs\"`) DO (
  REN "%%~fF.%%G.%%H.%%I" "%%F.%%G.%%I"
)
```

If you have files that vary in how many periods there are, just need to add a simple argument to count how many period delimiters exist then execute.

Answer (score 0):

Using [StringSolver](https://github.com/MikaelMayer/StringSolver), a semi-automatic renaming tool, just rename the first file, check that the generalized renaming is ok, and then accept it on all other files.

```
> move 1234567890123456.02232008.1946738250.pdf 1234567890123456.02232008.pdf
```

Get the explanation:

```
> move --explain

the file name until the end of the second number + the extension
```

If you are satisfied, you can run the semi-automated tool using `move --auto` or the succint version:

```
> move
```

DISCLAIMER: I am a co-author of this free software made for academic purposes.